# Java: How to parse XML comments using org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser?

Tags: java, xml, comments, xerces, saxparser

I managed to parse to comments from an XML file using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser, but is there a way to parse comments in org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser in Java? A simple example would be brilliant. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by parse comments in Java? You wish to add comment nodes? Or obtain the comment nodes from a parsed document?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a [LexicalHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPSAX11.html).